# Search TableView list in JavaFX

Tags: select, search, javafx, tableview

How to find a record in TableWie (for example via ID) and select founded Row and put it to the middle of the screen in Java 8 (JavaFX ).

Comment: What does it mean "put it to the middle of the screen in Java 8" ?

Answer (score 5):

You can search for an element using something like:

```
int searchId = ... ;

table.getItems().stream().filter(item -> item.getId()==searchId).findAny()
```

Then just use the usual methods to select the item (if there is one). The `TableView` has a `scrollTo(...)` method that will scroll so the item is visible:

```
table.getItems().stream()
    .filter(item -> item.getId() == searchId)
    .findAny()
    .ifPresent(item -> {
        table.getSelectionModel().select(item);
        table.scrollTo(item);
    });
```

If you have a very large number of items in the table, you may need to implement a more efficient search algorithm (e.g. sort by id and use a binary search as in @Bartek's answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search tableView it is best to do this:

- Sorting the list
- Binary search or simply loop check each line or agrees with the value sought

The list is as ArrayList so you can do it all.

Example [LINK](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/)

Comment: Well the easiest way is probably to wrap the `ObservableList` of the `TableView` in a `FilteredList`, as mentioned in your llnk.

Comment: You probably want to create a copy of the list before sorting, though, as you don't want to change the order of the displayed elements.