# JavaFX TableView Filter does not keep selection

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I implemented a simple filter on my JavaFX table view to allow a text field to display items that match its input ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398905/search-tableview-list-in-javafx) and [here](https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/)). While the filter works as expected, I would like the items selected while searching to be displayed again when all items are showing. If one item is selected while filtering, it will 'remember' only that item and no other items. Here is an example of my issue: [image]

I have tried to keep a list of selected items while using the search bar, and then setting these items to be selected when the search is finished, however my implementation failed. Is this the only way to accomplish retaining selections while searching? Am I missing a setting or an easier way?

Here is my code used for the filtering:

```
        FilteredList<TableItem> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(rTable.getItems(), p -> true);
    textFieldSearch.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        filteredData.setPredicate(myObject -> {
            // If filter is empty/null display all data
            if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            }
            //Otherwise try to match all fields
            String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();
            boolean b = myObject.hasField(lowerCaseFilter);
            return b;
        });
    });
    rTable.setItems(filteredData);
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: not supported: the basic issue is that FilteredList doesn't fire fine-grained change events on applying the filter, such that the selectionModel (or custom code) has no means to keep track

Comment: @kleopatra Interesting. So you are telling me that selections made during a filtered-list do not trigger selection events?

Comment: well, they do .. but changing the predicate fires a allChanged on the items so the selection cannot do much but reset everything, [the bug is on the side of the FilterredList](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092288)

Comment: What you really need is a CheckBox column... That way, instead of "selecting the row" you are "checking off the box" to denote a row as selected. The CheckBox would flip a flag on the data model, which should be retained.

Comment: @trilogy Another workaround could be the following: Store currently selected items before a search event and when the event is fired, select any on-screen items from the list and add these selections to our local list. When a search is complete (n characters in the field to 0 characters), select all items from the local list and then empty it.